# How to determine state of a collapsed element in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with button inside a reactjs which is collapsed using bootstrap@3.3.6

```
<div id="collapsing_button" className="collapse">
   <button>Collapse</button>
</div>
```

How do I determine if a button has been collapsed? Or how do I know a toggle between a collapsed and an un-collapsed state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understood you could use a [reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

```
<div id="collapsing_button" className="collapse" ref="collapsing_button">
```

this will make the DOM element available in your code:

```
render() {
    // just some pseudo-code demo
    let state = this.refs.collapsing_button.getAttribute('aria-hidden');
}
```